# IO.puts vs IO.inspect

Tags: elixir

It seems to me that `IO.puts` and `IO.inspect` are both used to print to the console. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Adding to the previous answer, `IO.inspect` can print an arbitrary elixir term, with an optional keyword list containing a `label:` and values for initializing an [Inspect.Opts](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Inspect.Opts.html#content) struct:

```
@spec inspect(item, Keyword.t) :: item when item: var
```

`IO.puts` requires the argument to be either a string, or a struct that implements the `String.Chars` protocol:

```
@spec puts(device, chardata | String.Chars.t) :: :ok
```

Comment: “arbitrary elixir term”—not an arbitrary, only those who implement [`Inspect.Algebra`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.4.4/lib/elixir/lib/io.ex#L293).

Comment: `Inspect.Algebra` is just a module that uses the `Inspect` protocol.  Inspect protocol appears to be implemented for all built in types and a generic implementation for structs (https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/inspect.ex)

Comment: Indeed, vice versa, yes.

Comment: @MikeBuhot If IO.Inspect also covers Strings, why have IO.puts separately?

Comment: @saishreb Because they do different things. Inspect allows pretty-printing, labels, width limits, etc. Puts just puts.

Comment: Try IO.puts and IO.inspect with a list of strings - you'll see very different outputs :)

Answer (score 7):

Reading through the Elixir docs, it looks like [`IO.puts/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/IO.html#puts/2) is simply going to write and append a newline.

[`IO.inspect/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/IO.html#inspect/2) will do the same thing, but it also returns the first value unchanged (so it's chainable), enables pretty printing/decoration and other formatting options.

- https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#inspect/2
- https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#print/2

Friendly reminder that hexdocs can be really awesome. I was able to easily find the answer to your question and learn the differences myself. I highly encourage you to read through modules you normally use to discover other functions you might not know about that you could be benefitting from.